# Java Spring MVC View Render and Bind ArrayList<CustomModel> back to Controller with Form Submit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, model-view-controller, taglib

I am having problems posting my ArrayList back to my controller on a Form Submit.  I can get my values by using something like this:

```
@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData
```

But this is not what I want, and this also provides my CSRF values which I don't care to evaluate on my form Submit.

I have a wrapper model class that looks like this:

```
public class CustomPayCodesWrapper {

    public ArrayList<CustomPayCodesModel> customCodes;

    public ArrayList<CustomPayCodesModel> getCustomCodes() {
        return customCodes;
    }

    public void setCustomCodes(ArrayList<CustomPayCodesModel> customCodes) {
        this.customCodes = customCodes;
    }
}
```

And my Model:

```
public class CustomPayCodesModel {

    public String codeName;
    public String codeValue;

    public String getCodeName() {
        return codeName;
    }

    public void setCodeName(String codeName) {
        this.codeName = codeName;
    }

    public String getCodeValue() {
        return codeValue;
    }

    public void setCodeValue(String codeValue) {
        this.codeValue = codeValue;
    }
}
```

My .jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${payCodes.customCodes}">
    <div class="row col-md-9">

         <div class="form-group row">
             <label for="payCode" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">${item.codeName}</label>
         <div class="col-md-10">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="payCode" name="${item.codeName}" value="${item.codeValue}">
             </div>
         </div>

     </div>
 </c:forEach>
```

I have tried the following Controller bindings without any success:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updateCustomPaymentCodes", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView updateCustomPayCodes(ModelAndView modelAndView, @ModelAttribute(value = "payCodes") CustomPayCodesWrapper userListWrapper, 
        ArrayList<CustomPayCodesModel> customCodes, @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> formData, CustomPayCodesWrapper userListWrapper2) {


    return showCustomPaymentCodes(modelAndView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SpringMVC looks for specific field format in the html posted to parse parameters. In the case of an array it is looking for the `name="customCodes[${status.index}].codeValue"` field. This will be turned into the HTML that is `name="customCodes[0].codeValue"` and `name="customCodes[1].codeValue"` and so on. These fields will be found and used to bind to a `List` or `Arrary` element. I was able to get just the list with the following:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public ModelAndView updateCustomPayCodes(@ModelAttribute CustomPayCodesWrapper payCodes) {
    payCodes.customCodes.forEach(m->System.out.println(""+m.codeName+":"+m.codeValue));
    return buildModelAndView();
}
```

and

```
    <c:forEach items="${payCodes.customCodes}" var="customCode" varStatus="status">
        <div class="row col-md-9">        
             <div class="form-group row">
                 <label for="payCode" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">${customCode.codeName}</label>
                 <input type="hidden" name="customCodes[${status.index}].codeName" value="${customCode.codeName}"/>
             <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customCodes[${status.index}].codeValue" value="${customCode.codeValue}"/>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </c:forEach>
```

This based on the tutorial [Spring MVC: Multiple Row Form Submit using List of Beans](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/) about doing the same

Comment: Thank you, you are right.  Using the hidden field + the index was the key.  Without the hidden field the bindings do not work, go figure!

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. The hidden field didn't have anything to do with the binding. The name="customCodes[${status.index}].codeName" field and its format is what handles the binding. See updates.